# Firebase Messaging is causing a crash on Xamarin iOS

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get this error in the console when I try to deploy the app, tried both on simulator and physical device. It displays the splash image then it backgrounds the app. No exception is thrown, the debugger just disconnects.
I am using Visual Studio for mac, the ios 13 sdk and the latest Firebase NuGets. Tried downgrading but nothing helps.

It seems that this only happens when I use Firebase Messaging. If I delete any of the code related to Firebase Messaging (but not deleting the NuGet) it works as intended.

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Description: DYLD, dependent dylib '@rpath/protobuf.framework/protobuf' not found for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DA138C0F-1292-4C17-A793-0443C743F7F6/ClubHub.iOS.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging', tried but didn't find: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DA138C0F-1292-4C17-A793-0443C743F7F6/ClubHub.iOS.app/Frameworks/protobuf.framework/protobuf' '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DA138C0F-1292-4C17-A793-0443C743F7F6/ClubHub.iOS.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/Frameworks/protobuf.framework/protobuf' '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DA138C0F-1292-4C17-A793-0443C743F7F6/ClubHub.iOS.app/Frameworks/protobuf.framework/protobuf' '@rpath/protobuf.framework/protobuf' '/System/Library/Frameworks/protobuf.framework/protobuf' Highlighted by Thread: 0
```

Yesterday I was getting a different error in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRApp registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x11034d9e8' *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23b98bde __exceptionPreprocess + 350 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff503b5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23bb9604 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132 3 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23b9d7bc ___forwarding___ + 1436 4 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23b9f6c8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120 5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff503bcdf0 load_images + 1226 6 ??? 0x0000000110c24d79 0x0 + 4576136569 7 ??? 0x0000000110c31970 0x0 + 4576188784 8 ??? 0x0000000110c30786 0x0 + 4576184198 9 ??? 0x000<…>
```

Comment: Could you share you Firebase Messaging code that you are adding? Also could you share more of your log/app input, and change it to Diagnostic Verbosity?

Comment: Anything. It happens even if AppDelegate just inherits from IMessagingDelegate. Will try sharing more logs, unfortunately cannot at the moment.

Comment: Is this on device and simulator?

Comment: Happens on both

Comment: Do you have FirebasePerformance installed on your app?

Comment: It seems has fixed in the latest version through [this thread](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/245#issuecomment-538693615), are you using the latest Firebase v6.5.0?

Comment: No, I have just Firebase Core, Auth, InstanceID and Messaging. Also, Firebase 6.5.0 is not there yet in Xamarin. Latest version is 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase packages for Xamarin iOS with below versions are working fine..

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.PerformanceMonitoring">
        <Version>8.10.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging">
        <Version>4.7.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FireBase.iOS.InstanceID">
         <Version>4.8.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FireBase.iOS.Core">
        <Version>8.10.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FireBase.iOS.Analytics">
        <Version>8.10.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations">
        <Version>8.10.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```